# Simplest form of multithreading in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

So, I have a portion of code that looks like the following.

```
for(a <- 0 until segments)
{
    // do something with elements at index a
}
```

What is the simplest type of multithreading, that can allow me to execute each element of that loop in a separate thread. I also have global collections (indexed by a) that need to be accessed by each thread. All I see on the internet are futures and actors, but they are quite difficult to grasp. I want something as simple as OpenMP.

I tried the following, but it gave me the error, `';' expected but '.' found. }} thread.start`.

```
for (a <- 0 until segments) {
    val thread = new Thread {
        override def run {
            // do something with elements at index a
        }} thread.start
}
```

Comment: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html

Comment: Not sure what you really want, but `Future.traverse`.

Comment: Maybe parallel collections would suit you? It won't execute each element on separate thread but it will split the work reasonably to use all your cores.

Comment: I don't want to go for parallel collections, as that would require me to change a lot of code.

Comment: do you mean "simplest" as in "shortest" or as in "low level"?

Comment: I meant simplest for the shortest and easiest.

Comment: @pythonic then you can consider https://github.com/scala/async as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asumed you are executing the code just for side effects.

Following code works. You get an error because `thread.start` should be in a separate line.

```
for (a <- 0 until 10) {
    val thread = new Thread {
        override def run(): Unit = { 
            // code
        }
    }
    thread.start()
}
```

you can replace it using futures, to use a thread pool which is much better than spawning possibly a large number of threads.

```
for (a <- 0 until 10) {
    Future {
        // code
    }
}
```

however in either case you won't be able to wait till it completes. You can traverse the range and get back the `Future` that will contains list of all partial results from each of the Futures you start using the second function.

```
val result: Future[List[Unit]] = Future.traverse((0 until 10).toList)(index => Future {
    // code
})
```

Having a `Future` result you can await on it, i.e. block calling thread until all computations are finished.

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.Await
Await.ready(result, 1.hour)
```

Use `Await.result` to get the result, `Await.ready` just waits till future is completed.

To wait for threads you would need to build a list when starting them and then call `join` on each.

I don't think you would need to change existing code to use parallel collections but maybe I don't know something specific to your code. Following code will split the range into chunks that will be processed in parallel.

```
for (a <- (0 until 10).par) {
   // code
}
```

With parallel collections you don't need to wait, thread will be blocked until everything is processed.

Comment: What do you mean won't be able to wait. What code do I need to add to wait then?

Comment: I edited my answer. If you won't wait, you will not know when your computations are done. Btw there is a great course on parallel programming in scala that I just finished today :p https://www.coursera.org/learn/parprog1/

Comment: @Łukasz you should use `Future.successful {}`  in example

Comment: I believe this is definitely something I shouldn't do as the OP wants to execute in multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong about parallel collections: they won't require you to change any code beyond what you actually want to change:

```
 (0 until segments).par.foreach { a =>
    // code
 }
```